# Error: Could not symlink Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers

Tags: python, homebrew, python-3.9

I am getting error while updating python to latest version.

```sh
brew update && brew upgrade python
```

```sh
9.0_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources -> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources
Error: Could not symlink Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers
Target /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers
is a symlink belonging to python@3.9. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink python@3.9

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python@3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the above problem.
Just try to link with overwriting as in the command below.

```sh
 brew link --overwrite python@3.9
```

It fixed my issue.